# Ruby: check if object has a method with particular signature, like respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to check if particular method signature is present in Ruby?

For example I want to call

```
thing.make(env: @@__ENV__, apiKey: "myKey")
```

if I do this check

```
if thing.respond_to? 'make'
```

I can end up with the error

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :apiKey
```

Is there a way to check that there is the particular `make(env:,apiKey:)` method and not just `make` with any arguments

Comment: I think not. But catching `ArgumentError` seems to be a good idea...

Comment: Try iterating over `thing.methods` and checking each `Method#arity` and `Method#parameters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is try it and rescue the ArgumentError.

```
begin
  thing.make(env: @@__ENV__, apiKey: "myKey")
rescue ArgumentError => e
  ...guess not...
end
```

You can also introspect the parameters of the [Method object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.4/Method.html#method-i-parameters). This returns an Array of Arrays like `[[:key, :env], [:key, :apiKey]]` . You're looking for `:key` if its optional, `:keyreq` if it's required.

```
params = thing.method(:make).parameters
p [:env,:apiKey].all? { |arg|
  params.include?([:key,arg]) || params.include?([:keyreq, arg])
}
```

---

If you have to do this as part of application code, you may want to reconsider your design.